# Change the datetime format in flutter for this week's first day

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I need to get the weeks first day as below format. the today comes good but not the first day. I can not assign the format for `DateTime.now().day % 1`
and `import 'package:intl/intl.dart';` has assigned.

```
final dateFormatter = DateFormat('yMd');
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String _today = DateFormat('yMd').format(now); //it is okay
var digit = DateTime.now().day % 1;
String digit2 = dateFormatter.digit; //I need this okay
```

Comment: I need current weeks first day and last day  in ('yMd') format

Comment: What is the `% 1` supposed to be doing?  That will always be 0.  Can you give some specific examples of what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works but is however not the best approach for this. The structure can be modelled to suit you question. print used here is for testing alone.

```
 int subs, day = DateTime.now().weekday;

  getdate() {
    switch (day) {
      case 1:
        subs = 0;
        break;
      case 2:
        subs = 1;
        break;
      case 3:
        subs = 2;
        break;
      case 4:
        subs = 3;
        break;
      case 5:
        subs = 4;
        break;
      case 6:
        subs = 5;
      break;
      default:
      subs =6;
    }

        print(DateTime(DateTime.now().year,
                      DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().day-subs));
  }
```